# Pentaho error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (connection to an oracle database)

Tags: database, oracle, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I've been having an IO error that doesn't allow me to connect to an oracle database

Error connecting to database: (using class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)
Erro de ES: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Any guess? how can i resolve this issue?

I tried to connect the oracle database with other data tools like power bi and it was successful, i have no idea why it is happening

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: From the error message it seems you have added the appropriate jdbc library to the corresponding folder, but it would help to indicate it to discard that error. What version of PDI, Oracle DB and JDBC connector are you using? Is the database multi-clustered? Providing a screenshot of how you are filling up the database connection information might give some clue, you don't need to use the real data, but if you are using this type of connection: server:port:SID to connect with the other tools, provide the screen shot to check you are correcting filling up the information.